# Splitting knitr Chunk code and output into two different knitrouts

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

The `knitr Chunk` option `results = "hold"` can put the output after the `Chunk Code`. I wonder how to split `knitr` Chunk code and output into two different `knitrouts` possibly with heading of `Code` and `Output`. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

<< label=Test, results = "hold" >>=
1:100
args(lm)
@ 
\end{document}
```

**Desired Output**

---

### Code

```
1:100
args(lm)
```

and

---

### Output

```
 [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
 [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
 [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
 [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
 [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
 [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = "qr", 
    model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, 
    contrasts = NULL, offset, ...)
```

**Edited**

I know this can be done by putting two chunks one showing only code and other showing only code. For long document this is an extra hassle. I wonder if this can be obtained with some hook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to play around with formatting, but you can achieve this by modifying the `source` [code hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks). What I show below is actually a very simple modification of the basic [`render_latex` hook](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/17e90bca2e798641b7f3c1ff7af0df12e4c97af9/R/hooks-latex.R) that adds `\\noindent\\textbf{Code:}` before the code and `\\noindent\\textbf{Output:}` after it:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
knit_hooks$set(
source = function(x, options) {
      x = knitr:::hilight_source(x, 'latex', options)
      if (options$highlight) {
        if (options$engine == 'R' || x[1] != '\\noindent') {
          paste(c('\\noindent\\textbf{Code:}\\begin{alltt}', x, '\\end{alltt}', '','\\noindent\\textbf{Output:}'),
                collapse = '\n')
        } else {
          if ((n <- length(x)) > 5) x[n - 3] = sub('\\\\\\\\$', '', x[n - 3])
          paste(c('\\noindent\\textbf{Code:}',x, '','\\noindent\\textbf{Output:}'),
                collapse = '\n')
        }
      } else .verb.hook(x)
    }
)
@

Here's your first chunk.

<<chunk1, results = "hold" >>=
1:100
args(lm)
@ 

And here's another.

<<chunk2, results = "hold">>=
1:5
6:10
@ 

That seems to be it.

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Thanks to a slight modification suggested by @mrbcuda in comments means you can separate the code and output frames:

Here's the modification of the `setup` chunk:

```
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
knit_hooks$set(
source = function(x, options) {
      x = knitr:::hilight_source(x, 'latex', options)
      if (options$highlight) {
        if (options$engine == 'R' || x[1] != '\\noindent') {
          paste(c('\\noindent\\textbf{Code:}\\begin{alltt}', x, '\\end{alltt}', '','\\end{kframe}\\begin{kframe}\\noindent\\textbf{Output:}'),
                collapse = '\n')
        } else {
          if ((n <- length(x)) > 5) x[n - 3] = sub('\\\\\\\\$', '', x[n - 3])
          paste(c('\\noindent\\textbf{Code:}',x, '','\\noindent\\textbf{Output:}'),
                collapse = '\n')
        }
      } else .verb.hook(x)
    }
)
@
```

And the resulting output:

[image]

Comment: (+1): Excellent @Thomas. Wonder how to split this `knitrout` into two: one for `code` only and second one for `output` only.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I tried a number of different things (child documents, code externalization, purling, etc.), but it does not seem that there is any easy way to split things up into separate output environments.

Comment: @Thomas a minor modification to the source hook accomplishes the separation via new `kframe`.  Insert '\\end{kframe}','\\begin{kframe}' into your paste statements just before the `\\noindent` for Output.

Comment: This is working fine except for `R Chunk` codes which have no outputs like this one `<< label=Test, results = "hold" >>= X <- 1:100 @`. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 5):

I'm unsure exactly what you want to do, but does this give you the desired output? I split the task into two chunks. First, I put off the evaluation of the first chunk and only print the output in the second.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\subsection{Code}
<<label=chunk1, eval=FALSE>>=
1:10
args(lm)
@

\subsection{Output}
<<label=chunk2, echo=FALSE>>=
<<chunk1>>
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can express the second chunk as `<<chunk2, ref.label="chunk1", echo=FALSE>>=
@`