# Splitting knitr chunk code and its output

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

This is the follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25060370/707145). My MWE with output is given below. The second R chunk code doesn't have any output. So I want not to split the knitrout into two pieces.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
knit_hooks$set(
source = function(x, options) {
      x = knitr:::hilight_source(x, 'latex', options)
      if (options$highlight) {
        if (options$engine == 'R' || x[1] != '\\noindent') {
          paste(c('\\noindent\\textbf{R Code:}\\begin{alltt}', x, '\\end{alltt}', '','\\end{kframe} \\noindent and \\begin{kframe}\\noindent\\textbf{R Output:}'),
                collapse = '\n')
        } else {
          if ((n <- length(x)) > 5) x[n - 3] = sub('\\\\\\\\$', '', x[n - 3])
          paste(c('\\noindent\\textbf{R Code:}',x, '','\\noindent\\textbf{R Output:}'),
                collapse = '\n')
        }
      } else .verb.hook(x)
    }
)
@

Here's your first chunk.

<<chunk1, results = "hold" >>=
1:100
args(lm)
@ 

And here's another.

<<chunk2, results = "hold">>=
X <- 1:100
@ 

That seems to be it.

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: set `results = 'hide'`?

Comment: Thanks @rawr for your comment. I need to evaluate for some reasons to use X in next chunks.

Comment: Setting `results = 'hide'` doesn't serve the purpose. Still getting un required output.

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly, you don't want the second code chunk to show up in your document but you want the code to evaluate.  Set `echo = FALSE` in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your hook, adding `results = 'hide'`. With your hook `and \\begin{kframe}\\noindent\\textbf{R Output:}'` is always printet.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
knit_hooks$set(
source = function(x, options) {
      x = knitr:::hilight_source(x, 'latex', options)
      if (options$highlight) {
        if (options$engine == 'R' || x[1] != '\\noindent') {
          if(options$results == 'hide'){
             paste(c('\\noindent\\textbf{R Code:}\\begin{alltt}', x, '\\end{alltt}'),
                  collapse = '\n')
          } else {
            paste(c('\\noindent\\textbf{R Code:}\\begin{alltt}', x, '\\end{alltt}', '','\\end{kframe} \\noindent and \\begin{kframe}\\noindent\\textbf{R Output:}'),
                  collapse = '\n')
          }
        } else {
          if ((n <- length(x)) > 5) x[n - 3] = sub('\\\\\\\\$', '', x[n - 3])
          paste(c('\\noindent\\textbf{R Code:}',x, '','\\noindent\\textbf{R Output:}'),
                collapse = '\n')
        }
      } else .verb.hook(x)
    }
)
@

Here's your first chunk.

<<chunk1, results = "hold" >>=
1:100
args(lm)
@ 

And here's another.

<<chunk2, results = "hide">>=
X <- 1:100
@ 

That seems to be it.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine except for such codes `<<label=test22, results="hide">>= ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(lm.D9)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))@` Any thoughts.

Comment: I don't get what's not working here. "R output" is not printed. Maybe you want `results='hide', fig.show='hold'`? If not, please update your question and example, to be more explicit about your problem.